# How To Add Custom Files After Post Title Field For Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

how to edit custom fields after post type field in wordpress post edit page ?
I am using WooCommerce for online shopping

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add fields under title box. add the below code in your functions.php in your theme file

**edit_form_after_title** fires after the title & permalink section is generated. where you can hook and add files. but this method is not preferable. instead you can add fields using metabox. is more preferable

**Add Fields :**

```
add_action('edit_form_after_title','wp_after_title_fields_34490557');


function wp_after_title_fields_34490557($post){  
  if($post->post_type == 'product'){

     echo '<select name="product_city">';
     echo '<option value="city1">city1</option>';
     echo '<option value="city2">City2</option>';
     echo '</select>';
  }
}
```

**Saving Posted Fields**

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_product_meta', 10, 3 );
function save_product_fields( $post_id, $post, $update ){
    if($post->post_type != 'product'){return ;}

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['publisher'] ) ) {
         update_post_meta( $post_id, 'city', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['product_city'] ) );
   }
}
```

Comment: Not working anymore with block editor